# Concatenate variable

Tags: twincat, codesys, structured-text

I need to concatenate a string and an integer and a string into a variable - in this case an input.

The inputs are named as following:

```
DI_Section1_Valve AT %I*: BOOL;
DI_Section2_Valve AT %I*: BOOL;
DI_Section3_Valve AT %I*: BOOL;
```

Now, I want to loop through these (this is just a short example):

```
For i:= 1 TO 3 DO
    Var[i] := NOT CONCAT(CONCAT('DI_Section', INT_TO_STRING(i)), '_Valve')
END_FOR
```

But by concatenating strings, I'll end up with a string, eg. 'DI_Section1_Valve', and not the boolean variable, eg. DI_Section1_Valve.

How do I end up with the variable instead of just the string?
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.
/Thoft99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That technique is called variable variables. Unfortunately this is not available in ST. There are few ways around it. As I understand Twincat 3 is based on Codesys 3.5. That means UNION is available. There is also a trick that references to `BOOL` does not work as expected and one reference take one byte. So you cannot place them in order, so you need to know `BYTE` address of input module.

```
TYPE DI_Bits : STRUCT
        DI_Section1_Valve  : BIT; (* Bit 1 *)
        DI_Section2_Valve  : BIT; (* Bit 2 *)
        DI_Section3_Valve  : BIT; (* Bit 3 *)
        DI_Section4_Valve  : BIT; (* Bit 4 *)
        DI_Section5_Valve  : BIT; (* Bit 5 *)
        DI_Section6_Valve  : BIT; (* Bit 6 *)
        DI_Section7_Valve  : BIT; (* Bit 7 *)
        DI_Section8_Valve  : BIT; (* Bit 8 *)
    END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

TYPE DI_Sections : UNION
        ByName : DI_Bits; 
        ByID : ARRAY[1..8] OF BOOL; (* Comment *)
        ByMask: BYTE;
    END_UNION
END_TYPE

PROGRAM PLC_PRG
    VAR
        DIS AT %IB0.0: DI_Sections; (* Our union *)
        xOut : BOOL;
    END_VAR


    xOut := DIS.ByID[1];
    xOut := DIS.ByName.DI_Section1_Valve;
    
    DIS.ByID[5] := TRUE; 
    // Now DIS.ByName.DI_Section5_Valve also EQ TRUE

END_PROGRAM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a variables by using strings. What you can do instead is manually create an array of pointers to the values you want to index, for example:

```
    DI_Section1_Valve AT %I*: BOOL;
    DI_Section2_Valve AT %I*: BOOL;
    DI_Section3_Valve AT %I*: BOOL;

    DI_Section_Valves: ARRAY [1..3] OF POINTER TO BOOL
        := [ADR(DI_Section1_Valve), ADR(DI_Section2_Valve), ADR(DI_Section3_Valve)];
```

```
    FOR i:= 1 TO 3 DO
        out[i] := DI_Section_Valves[i]^;
    END_FOR
```

EDIT: Alternatively, you could create a function that does this:

```
METHOD Get_DI_Selection_Valve : BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    i: INT;
END_VAR

    CASE i OF
    1: Get_DI_Selection_Valve := DI_Section1_Valve;
    2: Get_DI_Selection_Valve := DI_Section2_Valve;
    3: Get_DI_Selection_Valve := DI_Section3_Valve;
    END_CASE
```

```
FOR i:= 1 TO 3 DO
    out[i] := Get_DI_Selection_Valve(i);
END_FOR
```

The idea is the same though